# Windows 10 File History - does it automatically include subfolders?

Tags: windows, file-history

If I select `C:\Users\Foo` in the "Back up these folders" section of "Backup Options", will all the files within subfolders of 'C:\Users\Foo` be backed up?

Or do we have to select every single folder in whatever hierarchy we've created for managing our documents?

Comment: File history applies to files not folders

Comment: I should clarify: are the backups applied recursively to files within all the subfolders of a selected folder?

Comment: in short: yes. But this is easily verifiable, so IMO that's quite bad question. One caveat: file history does not follow symlinks and reparse points.

Comment: Interesting... I've ended up here because File History is *not* backing up all my subfolders from C:\Users\Foo - it's only backing up the files in the root and no Documents, Favorites etc. I suspect the C:\Users is handled differently because I'm also backing up E:\Projects and all sub-folders are going in. When you first set-up File History, it appears to list all the sub-folders in File History individually. I thought that was dead messy so removed them all and re-added just the root - bad idea!

Answer (score 2):

Win10 does not automatically back up folders recursively, as far as I can tell. I currently have two entire drives listed, and only the root level documents are saved.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't select every single folder one by one. 
If you select C:\Users\Foo, all folder in that Foo will be backup. By default, Windows 10's File History will back up all the folders in your User folder.
For more information, please read this Microsoft official document:

Back up and restore your files

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17143/windows-10-back-up-your-files

Answer (score -1):

On my system backup DOES NOT include subfolders.  Each folder must be setup individually for backup.  Finding program unreliable and going another direction as of 01/16/2021.